# Home Wi-Fi cannot access https://www.imperial.ac.uk/

Tags: networking, internet

I am able to access it using other Wi-Fi like my mobile data. Trying to access it using my home Wi-Fi gives me this

```
This site can’t be reached `www.imperial.ac.uk` took too long to respond.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I am from Singapore and have been able to access this website before both from my student apartment in London and my home in Singapore. I am still facing the same issue as of today (April 29, 2020) i.e. I cannot access it using my home Wi-Fi but can do it using some other Wi-Fi.

Comment: Please edit your question: Where are you located? In the UK? Have you been able to connect to this site before?

Comment: Could have something to do with the insecure http connection. The website doesn’t support https connections

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe. But if I run `curl -I www.imperial.ac.uk` it shows `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Comment: @JakeGould - The host is indeed configured to support insecure http connections.  I pointed out the fact, it's insecure, because the title of this question indicates https and I suspect a client side configuration that is not allowing http traffic (i.e. https everywhere plugin)

Comment: @Ramhound Got it. And HTTPS everywhere has tripped me up that way as well. Makes sense.

Comment: @JakeGould i have updated my post. I am currently residing in Singapore and was able to access the website from Singapore without any issues in the past.

Comment: Are you using a VPN, or, if not, have you considered using one for this website only. Your currently being in Singapore may or may not have anything to do with that, what with everything that's currently taking place in this part of the world (lockdown and all). You could also try to "forget" your WiFi network in Settings, and connect anew, after a "ipconfig /flushdns" command in command line. What are your current DNS settings? Are they enforced at modem level, or by your ISP in any other way, or can you set them manually? Your location may be the reason why you can't reach this website.

Comment: I am able to use mobile data to access the webpage from the same exact location

Comment: It does support HTTPS though...? It does not have a HTTPS redirect, for whatever reason. Which brings up an interesting test: Try both http://www.imperial.ac.uk and https://www.imperial.ac.uk

Comment: @DanielB the http returns an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET whereas the https an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Sounds like you’re getting actively blocked. Could by anything though—your ISP, the government, the university…. Traceroute _might_ show more, but don’t count on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
  tracert www.imperial.ac.uk
```

in command line it MAY tell you where on the journey the packets are getting stopped.  It looks like a proxy on your side is blocking you though.